# ifconfig parameter with store condition

Tags: php, magento

In Magento xml layut or config file we can write ifconfig as parameter in a tag to apply a condition like this

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts"     ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled">
<label>Contact Us</label>
<url>contacts</url>
<title>Contact Us</title>
<prepare>true</prepare>
</action>
```

I was trying to find ifconfig alternative of this function

```
Mage::getStoreConfig($path,Mage::app()->getStore());
```

so that i can include store condition along with path in ifconfig.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way to do that, mainly because the `ifconfig` constraint is used for the current store. When calling `Mage::getStroreConfig()` with only one parameter the current store is used as the second parameter. and the layout is loaded for the current store.
But if you insist, here is a possible idea on how to do it.
The `action` tags in the layout are parsed and applied in this method `Mage_Core_Model_Layout::_generateAction()`. This piece of code checks the `ifconfig` attribute.

```
if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

You can override this method to allow an additional parameter for the store. So your xml code would look like this:

```
<action method="someMethod" ifconfig="some/config/path" store="2" />
```

Now change the code above that calls the action to this:

```
if (isset($node['ifconfig']) && ($configPath = (string)$node['ifconfig'])) {
    if (isset($node['store'])){//check config setting for supplied store
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath, $node['store'])) {
            return $this;
        }
    }
    else{//default behavior
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath)) {
            return $this;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marvis. With little change your solution fulfilled my requirement. I set store="true" instead of store="2" and wrote store="true" and instead of if(!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath, $node['store'])) i wrote if(!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($configPath, Mage::app()->getStore())) So that it takes current store settings.

Comment: First of all is Marius (not Marvis) :). And second, you don't need that second parameter if you want to check the config value for the current store. If the second argument is not supplied, then the value for the current store is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Conditive Extended Ifconfig [extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extended-ifconfig-3120.html)